# How can I control class="active" in a submenu

Tags: 7, bootstrap-theme

I have a view with several exposed filters, they work fine. I added the unfiltered view in the main menu. Then I copied the urls of the filtered results to add them as submenu.

The "active" class is attibuted to the ‘better exposed filter’ links in the form I show to my visitors, ahead of the view.
But only one of the submenu links is attributed that "active" class, even though it doesn't fit the displayed result. Does anyone see where the problem can come from?

See for yourself: https://nature-et-sens.eu/boutique.

Edit ----
I figured that the problem is slightly different. Here is what the  submenu looks like (roughly):

```
<ul>
  <li class=""><a class="active" href="/boutique">…</a></li>
  <li class=""><a class="active" href="/boutique?some_filter">…</a></li>
  <li class="active-trail active">
    <a class="active" href="/boutique?some_other_filter">…</a>
  </li>
  <li>…</li>
</ul>
```

The only `<a class="active">` item which is properly styled is the one contained within the `<li class="active-trail active">`. I have no problem with that, my stylsheet complies accoardingly.

I would like to understand why this 'active-trail' class is always  attributed to the very same item, even though it is not the one I clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you, [here](http://webmar.com.au/blog/drupal-bootstrap-3-multilevel-submenus-hover)

Comment: That's not precicely what I needed, but it will be helpful for my next step. Thank you.